# FFMPEG HLS multiple Tracks not in sync

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, encode, http-live-streaming, mkv

This script works but the video doesnt sync with the sub or audio tracks.   Could someone help fix this or Help me with a NEW script.  I have been trying to figure this out with 0 luck and have had friends look at it.  I even went to FFMPEG discord and FB  asking for help from others who have posted scripts in the past.   Seems no one has a interest in this.   Please  will someone help me.

All I am trying to do is BULK encode  MKVs to HLS  with multiple resoutions  in 10 sec segments  and include all the Audio and SUb tracks that were originally in the MKV

````
$files = Get-ChildItem ${Get-Location}
$loco = Get-Location
$p1 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p1



function lnCodeTransform {
    param( $String )
    echo $String
    switch ($String)
    {
        "jpn" {"jp"}
        "eng" {"en"}
        "esp" {"es"}
        "fra" {"fr"}
        "deu" {"de"}
        default {$String}
    }
}


function lnNameTransform {
    param( $String )
    switch ($String)
    {
        "jpn" {"Japanese"}
        "eng" {"English"}
        "esp" {"Spanish"}
        "fra" {"French"}
        "deu" {"German"}
        default {$String}
    }
}


foreach ($f in $files){ 
    if ($f.Name -eq "out"){
        continue;
    }
    $p2 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out/" | Join-Path -ChildPath $f
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/audio
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/video
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/subtitle
    $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new();
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXTM3U' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-VERSION:3' )
    #[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360' )
    #[void]$sb.AppendLine( '360p.m3u8' )


    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2
    $resStr = ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $f.FullName;
    $res = [convert]::ToInt32($resStr)
    $audioTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
    $audioTracks = $audioTracks.split("\n")
    foreach($audio in $audioTracks) {
        $ID = $audio.split("|")[0];
        $audioName = $audio.split("|")[1];
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -threads 0 -muxdelay 0 -y -map 0:$ID -async 1 -codec aac -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/audio/audio_"$ID.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts out/$f/audio/"audio_$ID""_%d.ts"
        $name = lnNameTransform($audioName)
        $code = lnCodeTransform($audioName)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID=`"aac`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name`",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"audio/audio_$ID.m3u8`"" )
    }
    $subTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams s -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
    $subTracks = $subTracks.split("")
    foreach($subtitle in $subTracks) {
        $ID = $subtitle.split("|")[0];
        $subName = $subtitle.split("|")[1];
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -map 0:$ID -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/subtitle/sub_"$subName.m3u8" -segment_format webvtt -scodec webvtt out/$f/subtitle/"sub_$subName%d.vtt"
        $name = lnNameTransform($subName)
        $code = lnCodeTransform($subName)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID=`"subs`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name`",FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"subtitle/sub_$subName.m3u8`"" )
    }

    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1400000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=842x480,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/480p.m3u8' )
    #ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:a copy -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 -vf scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/480p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/720p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/1080p.m3u8
    #ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 23 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k  -keyint_min 4 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod  -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
    #ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -async 1 -profile:v main -y -filter:v scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480" -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/480p.m3u8
    If($res -ge 720) {
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -filter:v scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/720p.m3u8
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2800000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/720p.m3u8' )
    }   
    If($res -ge 1080) {
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -filter:v scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:1080" -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/1080p.m3u8
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5000000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/1080p.m3u8' )
    }

    $p3 = Join-Path -Path $p2 -ChildPath "/index.m3u8"
    #echo $index | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -LiteralPath $p3
    echo $sb.ToString()
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($p3, $sb.ToString().Trim().replace("`r`n", "`n"))
}
$sw.Stop()
echo $sw.Elapsed ```
````

Comment: Start with just one video. Get an ffmpeg command that works for you on just one video.  Then add the bulk conversation script later.

Comment: figured out the sync issue   but dont know how to change current script

Comment: woops lol   the issue is audio has to be done with at least the 480p encode so the video can set the pace. and because audio and sub share same parts i need to add it too..  but how do i still keep the naming system and all the tracks on a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
$files = Get-ChildItem ${Get-Location}
$loco = Get-Location
$p1 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p1



function lnCodeTransform {
    param( $String )
    switch ($String)
    {
        "jpn" {"jp"}
        "eng" {"en"}
        "esp" {"es"}
        "fra" {"fr"}
        "deu" {"de"}
        default {$String}
    }
}


function lnNameTransform {
    param( $String )
    switch ($String)
    {
        "jpn" {"Japanese"}
        "eng" {"English"}
        "esp" {"Spanish"}
        "fra" {"French"}
        "deu" {"German"}
        default {$String}
    }
}


foreach ($f in $files){ 
    if ($f.Name -eq "out"){
        continue;
    }
    $p2 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out/" | Join-Path -ChildPath $f
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/audio
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/video
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/subtitle
    $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new();
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXTM3U' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-VERSION:3' )
    #[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360' )
    #[void]$sb.AppendLine( '360p.m3u8' )


    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2
    $resStr = ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $f.FullName;
    $res = [convert]::ToInt32($resStr)
    $audioTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
    $audioTracks = $audioTracks.split("\n")
    foreach($audio in $audioTracks) {
        $ID = $audio.split("|")[0];
        $audioName = $audio.split("|")[1];
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -ss 0 -y -map 0:$ID -start_number 0 -codec aac -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/audio/audio_"$ID.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts out/$f/audio/"audio_$ID""_%d.ts"
        $name = lnNameTransform($audioName)
        $code = lnCodeTransform($audioName)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID=`"aac`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name`",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"audio/audio_$ID.m3u8`"" )
    }
    $subTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams s -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
    $subTracks = $subTracks.split("")
    foreach($subtitle in $subTracks) {
        $ID = $subtitle.split("|")[0];
        $subName = $subtitle.split("|")[1];
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -map 0:$ID -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/subtitle/sub_"$subName.m3u8" -segment_format webvtt -scodec webvtt out/$f/subtitle/"sub_$subName%d.vtt"
        $name = lnNameTransform($subName)
        $code = lnCodeTransform($subName)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID=`"subs`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name`",FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"subtitle/sub_$subName.m3u8`"" )
    }

    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1400000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=842x480,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/480p.m3u8' )
    #ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:a copy -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 -vf scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/480p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/720p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/1080p.m3u8
    #ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 23 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k  -keyint_min 4 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod  -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
    #ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 1200k -minrate 750k -maxrate 2100k -profile:v main -y -async 1 -force_key_frames:v "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2.000)" -filter:v scale=-2:480 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/480p.m3u8
    If($res -ge 720) {
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 2400k -minrate 1500k -maxrate 4200k -profile:v main -force_key_frames:v "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2.000)" -filter:v scale=-2:720 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/720p.m3u8
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2800000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/720p.m3u8' )
    }   
    If($res -ge 900) {
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 4800k -minrate 3000k -maxrate 8400k -profile:v main -force_key_frames:v "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2.000)" -filter:v scale=-2:1080 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/1080p.m3u8
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5000000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/1080p.m3u8' )
    }

    $p3 = Join-Path -Path $p2 -ChildPath "/index.m3u8"
    #echo $index | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -LiteralPath $p3
    echo $sb.ToString()
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($p3, $sb.ToString().Trim().replace("`r`n", "`n"))
}
$sw.Stop()
echo $sw.Elapsed ```
````